# Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Tags: mercurial

We have a Mercurial repository on our CI server that is available via Windows network share (`\\server\hg_repo`). Our team of 7 developers makes regular push's to and pulls from there. Also CI server itself does pulls obviously.

Periodically repository gets broken with error:

```
stdout: requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests

stderr: transaction abort!
rollback completed
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.1)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hg", line 42, in <module>
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 27, in run
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 64, in dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 684, in _dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 466, in runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 738, in _runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 692, in checkargs
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 681, in <lambda>
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 455, in check
File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 1137, in clone
File "mercurial\hg.pyo", line 347, in clone
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 2056, in clone
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1486, in pull
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1871, in addchangegroup
File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1157, in addgroup
File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 187, in deltachunk
File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 152, in chunklength
File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 17, in readexactly
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 863, in read
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 841, in splitbig
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1774, in gengroup
File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 1122, in group
File "mercurial\changegroup.pyo", line 244, in revchunk
File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 852, in revdiff
File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 831, in _chunk
File "mercurial\revlog.pyo", line 115, in decompress
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
```

Funny is that error may appear not for all developers e.g. CI server has error when I can do pull/push without error.

When we recreate central repo from some other copy it works fine again.

How to troubleshoot this error?

**

### UPDATE:

**

When it happened again today I run `hg verify` and its obfuscated output is below:

```
XXX> hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
hg.exe :  2355: reading manifest delta 2da8374dc3db: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ( 2355: reading ...ce too far back:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 2356: reading manifest delta 784e9c245c61: unknown compression type '\xfb'
 2357: reading manifest delta 5b147ce7d2a5: unknown compression type 'e'
 2358: reading manifest delta e1aa758953b2: unknown compression type '\xb3'
 2359: reading manifest delta 61dcc0da8106: unknown compression type 'F'
 2360: reading manifest delta 7579106dd2fe: unknown compression type '\xfa'
 2361: reading manifest delta b021c8e5ae34: unknown compression type '\xd2'
 2362: reading manifest delta 04e2a8673e61: unknown compression type '\x84'
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 XXX.csproj@2358: 564af8d2dcea not in manifests
 XXX.cs@2356: d1d2086e 9b69 not in manifests
.......... // here are more 'not in manifests errors'
20 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 2355)
14811 files, 3040 changesets, 31214 total revisions
```

Comment: What does `hg verify` say when its in that state?  Are you sure people are **only** getting data there via `hg push` and `hg pull`?

Comment: I did not run `hg verify` this time -- will do it when it fails again. Regardign `pull` and `push` -- yes, no other activity is being performed against that folder.